# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 in Archive

Tags: react-native, build

While i am trying to Archive a react native project, I am getting an error that is "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64".

Configuration is :-
React Native  :- "0.71.6"
React :- "18.2.0"
Xcode Version :- 14.2

The error is in the bellow :-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isabM.jpg)

Please help me to solve this problem.

Please help me to solve the error.

Comment: What you are building for device or simulator?
Do oyu have an intel or apple silicon?
Did you install pods?

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.